Characterizing the dual lattice of an real vector space
Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$, $V=$ {$(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbf{R}^n|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i=0$} be a real vector space, Let $l=V\cap\mathbf{Z}^n$ in $V$. Let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a restriction to $V$ of the standard Euclidean inner product on $\mathbf{R}^n$.
(In fact, $l$ is a even lattice).
I want to find the dual lattice $l^*=$ {$y\in V|(y,l)\subset\mathbf{Z}$}, and show that $l^*/l\cong\mathbf{Z}_n$.
My attempt:
Let $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in l^*$, Let $e_i=(0,...,1,...,0)$, where $1$ is in the $i$-component. (Note that $e_i-e_j\in l$)

$(y,e_1-e_2)=y_1-y_2\Rightarrow y_2=y_1+k_2$, for some $k_2\in\mathbf{Z}.$
$(y,e_1-e_3)=y_1-y_3\Rightarrow y_3=y_1+k_3$, for some $k_3\in\mathbf{Z}.$
$...$
$(y,e_1-e_n)=y_1-y_n\Rightarrow y_n=y_1+k_n$, for some $k_n\in\mathbf{Z}.$
Since $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in l^*\subset V$, so $y_1+...+y_n=0\Rightarrow ny_1+(k_2+...+k_n)=0
\Rightarrow y_1\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Z}.$
Similarly, $y_i\in \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Z}$ for all $i$.
Thus, we have $l^*\subset$ {$(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)\in V|y_i\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Z}$}.
Now, I wish we have $l^*=${$(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)\in V|y_i\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Z}$}.
But, if you consider $x=(1,-1,0)$, $y=(1/3,1/3,-2/3)$, then $(x,y)=2/3$ is not an integer. Thus, it seems that we can not have this kind of equality.
Maybe we can add more condition on the set {$(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)\in V|y_i\in\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{Z}$} to force the equality holds.
